# how to join 2 table and select a particular column using a common column in both tables

Tags: mysql

I am having 2 different tables like `table1` and `table2` in that  i have a common column `customer_id` and then i want to pick `customer_loan` from `table1` and `customer_name` from `table2` using the common column `customer_id` and join both and display in my page anyone help me

Comment: Did you try any query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is simple

```
SELECT table1.customer_loan,table2.customer_nam
FROM   table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON (table1.customer_id =table2.customer_id)
```

Comment: paranthesis are not needed though

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
select table1.customer_loan,table2.customer_nam from table1 inner join table2 on table1.customer_id = table2.customer_id
```

Comment: missing a column, op is aking for two columns to be returned

Answer (score 0):

You need a `JOIN`, like this:

```
SELECT table1.customer_loan, table2.customer_nam
FROM table1 JOIN table2 
USING (customer_id)
```